# Does the PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded event get called when the start button is pressed?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I do some clean up stuff in my PhoneApplicationUnloaded event on a xaml page. If I put a breakpoint inside the event, I can see that it gets hit if I use the backbutton to unload the page, or if I navigate forward anywhere, but if I use the start button to go back to the home screen, I don't see the breakpoint get hit.

Does this event really get called when you hit the start button? (maybe for some reason the emulator stops debugging when that happens and I don't see it get hit) or does it not. And if it doesn't what event should instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on MSDN that explains what happens when Start button is pressed and which event you should bind to. Whenever the application gets interrupted (like by a phone call or start button), it gets tombstoned, and the associated Application_Deactivated event is raised. Whenever the focus gets back to your application, you get Application_Activated event (where you're supposed to restore previous state).

Comment: Since I wish to handle both tombstoning and loading/unloading in the same manner (just in this particular case), I just changeed my unloaded/loaded events to be OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom. Thanks for the link! makes me feel silly for not reading msdn better

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the start button doesn't unload the application, the other scenarios do unload the application.  Put the code in your Unload event into a common class that both the Unload event and the button click event can call.